# Why does KNN Model return 99% accuracy on dataset with default parameters?

Tags: classification, binary-classification, accuracy, scikit-learn, k-nearest-neighbors

[image: This is how a sample of my data looks like]
I am building a model that predicts if a user will like a stock or not based on different features, such as Market Cap, Current Ratio, Sector, Trailing PE, etc. I am going to implement this model in a website, where the model is able to adapt over time to user preferences. I made an example dataset that generally represents how the data that gets passed to the model will look. I have build a KNN model based on that sample dataset, and I get 99% accuracy on the training split and test split. I also get 98%-99% on my classification report even though I have class imbalance, about 500 of one class, and 10500 of another class. My macro average and weighted average are both 99%. I was planning on optimizing this model by hyper tuning, but does anyone know why I got 99% accuracy immediately? This is how a sample of my data looks like above.
Here is some of my code:

```
X = data.drop(["Stocks", "target"], axis = 1)
y = data["target"]
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

categorical_features = ["sector", "quoteType"]
one_hot = OneHotEncoder()
transformer = ColumnTransformer([("one_hot",
                                  one_hot,
                                  categorical_features)],
                               remainder = "passthrough")

X = transformer.fit_transform(X)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X) 
X = pd.DataFrame(X)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

np.random.seed(42)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(metric = "minkowski")
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
knn.score(X_test, y_test)

y_preds = knn.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(y_test, y_preds))

This produces:
precision    recall  f1-score   support

           0       0.98      1.00      0.99      1227
           1       1.00      0.98      0.99      1012

    accuracy                           0.99      2239
   macro avg       0.99      0.99      0.99      2239
weighted avg       0.99      0.99      0.99      2239
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140489/discussion-on-question-by-messi10-why-does-knn-model-return-99-accuracy-on-data).

Answer (score 1):

First assess whether the accuracy is unreasonably high.  You as the domain expert are the best arbiter of that.  Keep in mind that a high accuracy is not always impossible.  For example, 99% accuracy can be seen on MNIST digits dataset.  It is also possible that you have [data leakage](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-leakage-machine-learning/), so assess whether this may be at play. The second thing you can do is perform an [n-fold cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html).  This will provide you with a better estimate (and error bounds) for your model's performance.  If your accuracy remains high on all folds, then you can exclude a spurious split on your holdout validation.

Another issue is that you claim that you have an imbalanced dataset.  However, your print out shows roughly equal support for 0 and 1 classes.

Finally, you are performing preprocessing of your features on the total dataset.  Instead, you should apply `fit_transform` on your training data, and the just apply the `transform` on your test data.

Comment: I have an imbalanced dataset but the data I show above is just a sample of what my data looks like. Also, why should I should apply fit_transform on my training data, and just apply the transform on my test data?

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  In that case, I would say that it is customary to perform evaluation on the total test set, not just a subset that you selected, regardless of whether your dataset is balanced or not.  Regarding the second issue of fit / fit_transform, the suggestion has to do with data leakage.  see [article](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/common_pitfalls.html#data-leakage)

Comment: I ran a classification report and it returned a score of 0.99 as shown above, so does that say that the model was able to generalize well?